# How to organize the commonly used view (HTML) files in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am creating a large scale application using AngularJS which is a Single Page App. I kept  all the script files under the folder Scripts like below.

```
Scripts
    Sample
        SampleModel.js 
        SampleService.js
        SampleController.js

    Sample1
        Sample1Model.js 
        Sample1Service.js
        Sample1Controller.js
```

and my view files as below

```
Views
    Sample
        sample.html
        sampleheader.html
        samplefooter.html
    Sample1
        sample1.html
        sampleheader.html
        samplefooter.html
```

I have same content for header and footer in both the Sample and Sample1 folder. I want to make it as common for all the screens which I am going to create.

Please advise the best way, to organize the commonly used HTML files?

Comment: You may put common content in some Scripts/Common folder and use ng-include directive to attach to it samples. Also, look at [this](https://github.com/ngbp/ng-boilerplate) repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a structure like this:

```
Views
  Samples
    sample.html
    sample1.html
    Common
      sampleheader.html
      samplefooter.html
```

And build up your main view like this:

```
<div ng-view>
  <!-- your app routing routes to sample.html, sample1.html, ... -->
</div>
```

Content of a "sample.html":

```
<div ng-include="'Views/Samples/Common/sampleheader.html'"></div>
<!-- your special sample code here -->
<div ng-include="'Views/Samples/Common/samplefooter.html'"></div>
```

The routing would look like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('/sample', 
       {templateUrl: 'Views/Sample/sample.html', controller: SampleController})
     .when('/sample1', 
       {templateUrl: 'Views/Sample/sample1.html', controller: SampleController})
    ;
})
```